# Delete edges on the top of geometry in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, edges

I want to delete the edges at the top of the geometry.

I took 2 screenshots: the first is the geometry I made and the second is the one I want at the end. I deleted the edges using the position node, but that's not what I want. I want it to be deleted at every angle, only at the top of this geometry.

[image: initial пeometry]

[image: wanted geometry]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By fetching the normals of the faces with the node `Transfer Attribute`, and calculating the dot product with the vector $0,0,1$ (pointing upwards), you can create a selection.

If the dot product is greater than $0$, the upward pointing face is selected.

With the node `Delete Geometry` you can then delete the edges that are connected to the face.

[image]

However, if your geometry doesn't have faces, you can directly turn the edges into a selection in a similar way:

[image]

And the third solution would be to simply use the Z position of the edges as a criterion for selection:

[image]

Comment: I think you've duped image 3.  Input should be edge-normal  in Image 2? ;)

Comment: @RobinBetts Uh, no, the images are different. But in that case (Cube on 0,0,0) it doesn't make any difference anyway, does it?

Comment: Ahhh I see! sorry, @quellenform . From your description, I was expecting [this one](https://imgur.com/a/amR375R), (from the interpolated edge-normal), and so misread it.

Comment: That was useful, thanks