# Geometry nodes: align objects spawned on faces to their normals (y), bottom edge (-z) and bottom edge direction (x)

Tags: geometry-nodes

I use **Face normal** and **[face bottom edge](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/311471/geometry-nodes-how-to-select-the-top-edges-of-faces/311489#311489)** direction, to calculate instance orientation per face. but some of the instances are flipped.

[image]

I think the problem is with calculating the vector of **face bottom edge**.

[image]

I tried using maximum and minimum math nodes, but it doesn't work. any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use the same rotation to rotate a vector $<0, 0, 1>$, separate its $z$ component, pass to a switch, if false, rotate euler by $180°$ around local $z$ axis.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I don't know how to implement it. plz, explain more.